# T-SQL Using a varchar in a select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to use the return of a function (VARCHAR) as columns in a select statement. For example:

A function fn1 returns a varchar @result='Alice,Bob'. How can I do a query using @result in a select statement, e.g:

```
SELECT @result FROM B
```

and obtain the records of the columns Alice and Bob of another Table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is not clear, are you have a function which set value of @result? You want to select all values from table B where some column value equal to @eresult variable value?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Can you clarify the input and output that you are expecting. Your example of "SELECT @result FROM B" does not help!

Comment: @doitgood "tsql" => MS SQL Server

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using and please clarify your input and output that you are expecting. Do you want to return a table and being able to filter it...?

Comment: I will try to give a more concrete example, though a bit stupid:
The function FN_1 returns a varchar @result='id,name,age' (using coalesce), and now I need to use this result to do a query like this:
`SELECT @result FROM B`

And obtain the records of columns id,name and age, of the table B 

The problem is that the queries processor does not parse id,name and age as columns but as a normal string

Thanks

Comment: @AakashM - Can also mean Sybase.

Comment: Can this link be of any help : http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/06/converting-delimited-string-of-values.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `exec('select ' + fn_1() + ' from T')`